# Change the property names in a JSON object before conversion to XML

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net

I am trying to convert some JSON to XML, but before that I need to change some properties to make a successful conversion.

Some of the properties in the JSON structure start with numbers, and when I try to make the conversion to XML I get an error because XML does not admit tags that start with numbers.

So, one solution that works for me is to change those property names that start with numbers by adding a prefix to the property.

I have been trying to do something like this:

```
public string ChangeNumericalPropertyNames(JsonReader reader)
{
    JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);

    foreach (JProperty jp in jo.Properties())
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(jp.Name, @"^\d"))
        {
            string name = "n" + jp.Name; 

            //Logic to set changed name
        }
    }

    return "Here I want to return the entire json string with changed names";
}
```

When I try this:

```
jp.Name = name;
```

Visual studio says that is not possible because `jp.Name` is read only.

Does anybody know how to achieve this solution?

Comment: replace the property name in the json string and then serialize the json.

Comment: Is not that simply, because I don't know how to set the name. Is not possible to do something like jp.Name = name, because jp.Name is read only

Comment: take your json string and modifiy it - idk, do a `Regex.Replace()` then Serialize that modified string.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since the property name is read only, you'll need to replace the whole property.  You can use the `Replace` method to do this:

```
        if (Regex.IsMatch(jp.Name, @"^\d"))
        {
            string name = "n" + jp.Name;
            jp.Replace(new JProperty(name, jp.Value));
        }
```

However, this will lead to another problem-- since you are trying to modify the `Properties` collection of the `JObject` while iterating over it, Json.Net will throw an `InvalidOperationException`.  To get around this, you must copy the the properties to a separate list and iterate over that instead.  You can do that using the `ToList()` method in your `foreach` like this:

```
    foreach (JProperty jp in jo.Properties().ToList())
```

Finally, to convert the updated `JObject` back to JSON, just use `ToString().`  Putting it all together we have:

```
public static string ChangeNumericalPropertyNames(JsonReader reader)
{
    JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);

    foreach (JProperty jp in jo.Properties().ToList())
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(jp.Name, @"^\d"))
        {
            string name = "n" + jp.Name;
            jp.Replace(new JProperty(name, jp.Value));
        }
    }

    return jo.ToString();
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rX4Jyy

---

The above method will only handle a simple JSON object with properties all on one level.  You indicated in your comment that your actual JSON is not flat, but hierarchical.  In order to replace all of the numeric property names in a hierarchical structure, you'll need to make your method recursive, like this:

```
public static string ChangeNumericalPropertyNames(JsonReader reader)
{
    JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
    ChangeNumericalPropertyNames(jo);
    return jo.ToString();
}

public static void ChangeNumericalPropertyNames(JObject jo)
{
    foreach (JProperty jp in jo.Properties().ToList())
    {
        if (jp.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            ChangeNumericalPropertyNames((JObject)jp.Value);
        }
        else if (jp.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            foreach (JToken child in jp.Value)
            {
                if (child.Type == JTokenType.Object)
                {
                    ChangeNumericalPropertyNames((JObject)child);
                }
            }
        }

        if (Regex.IsMatch(jp.Name, @"^\d"))
        {
            string name = "n" + jp.Name;
            jp.Replace(new JProperty(name, jp.Value));
        }
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qeZK1C

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help. I tried your solution and it works with properties at the same level. But I have an Exception when the json is like this,

{
  1: "one",
  2: {
         3:"three"
      }
}

When the numerical name is a property of another property.

Comment: You'll need a recursive method to handle that.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!